# jQuery: How can I add a div to cover the element the mouse over?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to add a div to cover the element which the mouse hover  in a web page. I tried as follows,but it failed. How can I do it? Thanks!

```
  jQuery(function ($) {

    $("*").bind("mouseenter.noteEvent", function (event) {

    var offset = $(this).offset();
    var enterBg = "<div id = 'tooltip_enterbg'></div>";
    $("body").append(enterBg);
    $("#tooltip_enterbg")
        .css({
                "top": offset.top + "px",
                "left": offset.left + "px",
                "width": $(this).width(),
                "height": $(this).height(),
                "opacity": 0.5,
                "background-color": "#FFFF00"}
        );

    });

    $("*").bind("mouseleave.noteEvent", function (event) {
       $("#tooltip_enterbg").remove();
    });

});
```

**[jsfiddle Demo:](http://jsfiddle.net/Mv472/6/)**
 In this demo, when the mouse move to "AAA",  the whole page turn lightyellow, I only want the  "AAA" to turn lightyellow.

Comment: Side note: You're hooking those event handlers up to a ***lot*** of elements. You might consider event delegation -- `$("body").on("mouseenter", "*", function() { ... });`

Answer (score 0):

The bit you're missing out is `position: absolute`, e.g.:

```
$("#tooltip_enterbg")
    .css({
            "top": offset.top + "px",
            "left": offset.left + "px",
            "width": $(this).width(),
            "height": $(this).height(),
            "opacity": 0.5,
            "background-color": "#FFFF00",
            "position": "absolute"}     // <===== Here
    );
```

---

Side note:

There's no need to look up the element you just appended. Change

```
var enterBg = "<div id = 'tooltip_enterbg'></div>";
$("body").append(enterBg);
$("#tooltip_enterbg")
    .css/*...*/
```

to

```
var enterBg = $("<div id = 'tooltip_enterbg'></div>");
$("body").append(enterBg);
enterBg
    .css/*...*/
```

Comment: I tried `"position": "absolute"`, but he affect is that the whole page turn lightyello, I only want the div to cover a little section.

Comment: @tao4yu: You need `position: absolute` in order to position the div. If it's not where you want it to be, you need to look at its metrics in dev tools and figure out why it's not where you want it to be, but that part is not optional.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```
jQuery(function ($) {

    $("p").bind("mouseenter.noteEvent", function (event) {

    var offset = $(this).offset();
    var enterBg = "<div id = 'tooltip_enterbg'></div>";
    $("body").append(enterBg);
    $("#tooltip_enterbg")
        .css({
                "top": offset.top + "px",
                "left": offset.left + "px",
                "width": $(this).width(),
                "height": $(this).height(),
                "opacity": 0.5,
                "background-color": "#FFFF00",
                "position": "fixed"}
        );
    });

    $("p").bind("mouseleave.noteEvent", function (event) {
       $("#tooltip_enterbg").remove();
    });
});
```

The demo is here: http://jsfiddle.net/Mv472/3/